# Coralogix opensearch - Fetching data

Tags: opensearch

I'm attempting to use the [OpenSearchAPI](https://coralogix.com/docs/opensearch-api/) and attempting to pull data and the below snippet always results with `Caused by NewConnectionError` error.
Within Coralogix - I've generated the log query API key.
I attempted the urls associated with Europe as well and the error wasn't any different.

```
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "token": "XXXX"
}
#url = 'https://tradeweb-ifi.app.coralogix.us:9443/*/_search?scroll=5m'
url = 'https://esapi.coralogix.us:9443/*/_search?scroll=5m'
with open('a.json', 'r') as w:
    json_data = w.readlines()
try:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print("All Well!")
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as request_exception:
    print("Request exceoption:", request_exception)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_error:
    print("Http Error:", http_error)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as connection_error:
    print("Connection Error:", connection_error)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as timeout_error:
    print("Timeout:", timeout_error)
```

Is there anything specific to accessing Coralogix/OpenSearch that I'm missing out on?